# Are questions about sports media distribution on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

> This is in reference to [Where can I watch the NFL online?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/where-can-i-watch-the-nfl-online)

There is a lot of confusion as to how NFL content is distributed online.  It is of value for an observer of the NFL to learn how they can watch an NFL game when not near a television.

Sample ideal answers:

- The NFL streams content on its website at nfl.com.
- NFL games are distributed by their networks, such as NBC.  If the network offers streaming via their website, you can watch it there.
- The NFL currently prohibits online distribution of its media [reference]

Can this question be improved to be constructive?  If not, why?

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is merely a search request. Rephrase your question to elaborate your intent, and I will consider reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question started, "There is a lot of confusion as to how NFL content is distributed online," then it could very well be constructive. With this perspective, one may research the **legal** ways how the NFL distributes their media according to their rules/legal statements. These legal ways could be through nfl.com, broadcast tv, etc.

The NFL has rules/legalites on media distribution (as stated in their famous "prohibited" statement during their events)...and this would surely be on-topic.

Comment: I have revised the question, let me know if it still has issues.